# Excel: How to count specific character in a cell range for different categories in a separate range

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet matrix where,
Column A contains staff name, Column B contains 2 rows per staff namely "Roster" and "Actual", and column C through I contains the week days.

For the Rows "Roster" and "Actual" against every staff, the inputs under the weekdays are:
M for Morning shift.
E for Evening shift.
N for Night shift.
ME for Morning plus Evening
EN for Evening plus Night

I would like to count the daily number of M, E and N; separately for "Roster" and "Actual". I have tried Sumproduct with Len and Len(Substitute). But that considers both Roster and Actual together. Please help.

Comment: Some cells contain e.g ME. Countifs would not count M and E separately in such a case.

Comment: No idea about wildcard

Comment: Pls help me how i can use it to get my job done. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Assuming that `B2` is "Roster" and column `C` is "Monday", then "Roster M for Monday", should be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INT(MOD(ROW(C2:C9)-ROW(C2),2)=0),INT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*M*",C2:C9))))
```

And if `B3` is "Actual", then "Actual M for Monday" should be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INT(MOD(ROW(C2:C9)-ROW(C3),2)=0),INT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*M*",C2:C9))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I have got it done with Wildcard. That's easier!

Comment: For Actual Morning count of Monday: Countifs(C2:C15,"*M*",B2:B15,"Actual")

Answer (score 0):

This is how I suppose your data looks like:

[image]

Please type in the formula in cell C17:

```
={SUMPRODUCT(INT(IF($B$2:$B$15=$A17,1,0)),INT(IF(LEFT(C$2:C$15,1)=$B17,1,0)))+SUMPRODUCT(INT(IF(LEN(C$2:C$15)=2,1,0)),INT(IF(RIGHT(C$2:C$15,1)=$B17,1,0)),INT(IF($B$2:$B$15=$A17,1,0)))}

ctrl+shift+enter
```

Then drag and drop. Hope this helps!